# Subpatterns in regular expressions don't work properly

Tags: php

I tried it now:

```
preg_match_all('/(dog)/', 'dog cat dog', $matches);
```

And it gives a result of empty array. PCRE is enabled and works correctly with ordinary expression like `'/dog/'`.

php 7.1.9

Comment: This code works here, with two matches of dog.

Comment: Works fine ... [Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/086588bc139bb6cc254e7fd836cedba234956e60)

Comment: Maybe I need to reinstall Apache and php